# Compute orthogonal complement using BLAS / LAPACK

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, blas, orthogonality

Is there a fast method to compute an orthogonal complement of an arbitrary matrix $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ in BLAS / LAPACK?

Specifically, I want any matrix $V\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times (m - \text{rank}(M))}$ such that
$$
\text{rank}(U|V) = m.
$$

The singular value decomposition methods in LAPACK can do this if called correctly, but if $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times (m-1)}$ is full rank, this will take $O(m^3)$, when it should only take $O(m^2)$ (e.g., via Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of a random vector).

Orthogonality of $V$ is a plus but not required.

Comment: Are you assuming $U$ has orthogonal columns? Otherwise I don't think a Gram-Schmidt-type algorithm would be guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Federico, good point. I didn't really mean to assume that. And I guess the only practical situation where I'd know I have orthogonal columns would be after just having run an $O(m^3)$ algorithm like "non-full" SVD or QR

Comment: I mean, I don't think running a Gram-Schmidt-like process ensures that you get a valid solution, unless $U$ was already orthogonal to start with. So I'm not sure that there is a $O(m^2)$ solution as you claim in the case $n=m-1$.

Comment: And then the next question is: can you assume $U$ to have full column rank? Otherwise, checking it requires $O(mn^2)$ to start with.

Comment: (And let me also note that in practice in this case taking a random $V$ works with probability 1!)

Comment: "So I'm not sure that there is a $O(m^2)$ solution as you claim in the case n=m−1" -- yes, my comment was meant to convey that I agree with you. As in, if the only way to have a $O(m^2)$ solution is to run $O(m^3)$ first (to get orthogonal $U$), there is no point. So do you think SVD is the best way to solve this then?

Comment: Oh OK. QR factorization is faster than SVD, but yes, I agree with you that there does not seem to be anything better that works provably and stably. You can represent $Q$ and $V$ implicitly if $n \ll m$ and save some work, but you seem to be interested in the opposite case ($m-n\ll m$).